# Reputation Graphs have been wound backwards!

Tags: bug, design, user-profile

**This picture should say it all.**

[image]

As you can see, selecting the bar (for example, the one on the 6<sup>th</sup> of August displays I have 245 reputation earned on the day. The only problem is that it actually displays the reputation that I have received on the previous day.

*Note that the bar graph said I earned 245 reputation on that day, but the values down below (added up) only total to 129 reputation.*

[image]

So:

- Are the graphs bugged and somehow became wound back one day?
- Is it by design?
- Or it that the detail list is wound forward by a day?

And, **any way to fix?**

---

I'm using Winows Edge on Windows 10 and Google Chrome on Windows 7.
*Yes, I'm using two computers.*

They're both experiencing that issue.

**Edit:** Could it be an error in cached data?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but mine are accurate..

Comment: Does the problem happen when you clear your cache? And does the same thing pop up on chrome as it does for microsoft edge? Bit too early to consider issues unique to edge with how early it still is (heck they havnt even got "save as" working). I use Mozilla Firefox. Ill check on my androids Chrome, just in case

Comment: @Timelord64 - When I said 'cached', I meant on SE's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems to be a bug an I can 100% reproduce it on Chrome and Edge, dont have tried Firefox.

[image: Graph Bug?]

However I'm not able to fix it on my client side e.g. clearing cache.

The graph raw data seems to be corrent **[2014,8,12,100]** (shows 100 rep on august 12th 2014) stole it from the javascript part.
[image: Graph to raw data]